# Understanding a boost executor example

Tags: c++, boost

I am having problems with understanding why an (undocumented) interface of `boost::basic_thread_pool executor` is used in this example below taken from the [boost documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.executors.examples.quick_sort) itself:

```
template<typename T>
struct sorter
{
    boost::basic_thread_pool pool;
    typedef std::list<T> return_type;

    std::list<T> do_sort(std::list<T> chunk_data)
    {
        if(chunk_data.empty()) {
            return chunk_data;
        }

        std::list<T> result;
        result.splice(result.begin(),chunk_data, chunk_data.begin());
        T const& partition_val=*result.begin();

        typename std::list<T>::iterator divide_point =
            std::partition(chunk_data.begin(), chunk_data.end(),
                           [&](T const& val){return val<partition_val;});

        std::list<T> new_lower_chunk;
        new_lower_chunk.splice(new_lower_chunk.end(), chunk_data,
                               chunk_data.begin(), divide_point);
        boost::future<std::list<T> > new_lower =
             boost::async(pool, &sorter::do_sort, this, std::move(new_lower_chunk));
        std::list<T> new_higher(do_sort(chunk_data));
        result.splice(result.end(),new_higher);
        while(!new_lower.is_ready()) {
            pool.schedule_one_or_yield();
        }
        result.splice(result.begin(),new_lower.get());
        return result;
    }
};
```

The call in question is **`pool.schedule_one_or_yield();`**. Correct me if I am wrong, but it suggests that a submitted task will be eventually scheduled for execution. If so, should not have each previous call to **`boost::async(pool, &sorter::do_sort, this, std::move(new_lower_chunk));`** already scheduled the submitted tasks implicitly?

I know the boost executor API is experimental, but do you know why `schedule_one_or_yield` is undocumented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `schedule_one_or_yield()` was removed from the current source code  of boost because it implemented *busy waiting*. This is in

**https://github.com/boostorg/thread/issues/117**

> loop_executor::loop is currently:

```
void loop()
{
  while (!closed())
  {
    schedule_one_or_yield();
  }
  while (try_executing_one())
  {
  }
}
```

> The first loop repeatedly calls schedule_one_or_yield() which is simply

```
void schedule_one_or_yield()
{
    if ( ! try_executing_one())
    {
      this_thread::yield();
    }
}
```

current implementation `loop_executor::loop` of is

```
/**
     * The main loop of the worker thread
     */
    void loop()
    {
      while (execute_one(/*wait:*/true))
      {
      }
      BOOST_ASSERT(closed());
      while (try_executing_one())
      {
      }
}
```

source : https://github.com/boostorg/thread/blob/develop/include/boost/thread/executors/loop_executor.hpp

It was also removed in the example `user_scheduler`, the old version is in

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/third_party/boost-1.60.0/boost/thread/user_scheduler.hpp with `schedule_one_or_yield()` in line 63

the new version without `schedule_one_or_yield()` is in  https://github.com/boostorg/thread/blob/develop/example/user_scheduler.cpp